# How to unescape request path in Integration Request (AWS APIGateway)

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm writing a mobile application in Swift 3 and using AWS APIGateway, Lambda and RDS.  In the POST method, I'm passing a unique identifier in one of the elements of the body such as:

us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-55b0-4917-82e3-85b3b093fa9c

However, in a GET method, I'm using a Request Path to retrieve this user record and passing this value.  However, I'm guessing it's getting encoded since it's a request path and resulting with:

us-east-1%3Axxxxxxxx-55b0-4917-82e3-85b3b093fa9c

Once it hits Lambda this way (and my RDS), it will not find the record due to the escaping of the colon.  As such, can I "unescape" this value in the Integration Request template?

I've tried a template such as:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "user_identity" : "$util.decodeURIComponent($input.params('useridentity'))"
}
```

However, that doesn't work.  I get the following in my logs:

```
Thu Aug 17 02:32:47 UTC 2017 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /user/us-east-1%3Axxxxxxxx-55b0-4917-82e3-85b3b093fa9c
Thu Aug 17 02:32:47 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {
   "user_identity" : ""
}
```

I've also tried using decodeURI but that gives me the same result.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dang!  I literally found the answer a few minutes after I posted this.  Here was the solution:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "user_identity" : "$util.urlDecode($input.params('useridentity'))"
}
```

The urlDecode function did the trick.  I hope this helps someone else!!

Comment: Not Dang! This helped a lot. Also FYI for those coming to this question, if you typo the function call above, it will just silently return an empty string, rather than some type of error.